# Is there an easily available implementation of erf() for Python?

Tags: python, math

I can implement the error function, erf, myself, but I'd prefer not to. Is there a python package with no external dependencies that contains an implementation of this function? I have found [this](http://pylab.sourceforge.net/packages/included_functions.html) but this seems to be part of some much larger package (and it's not even clear which one!).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Since v.2.7. the standard *math* module contains *erf* function. This should be the easiest way.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.erf

Comment: Is there a Python module that provides erf⁻¹(x) ?

Comment: @Lori - yes, math.erfc

Comment: @Matthew I don't think that's correct according to documentation. That calculates 1.0 - erf(x). The inverse of erf() is in SciPy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266249/command-for-inverse-erf-function-in-python

Answer (score 61):

I recommend SciPy for numerical functions in Python, but if you want something with no dependencies, here is a function with an error error is less than 1.5 * 10<sup>-7</sup> for all inputs.

```
def erf(x):
    # save the sign of x
    sign = 1 if x >= 0 else -1
    x = abs(x)

    # constants
    a1 =  0.254829592
    a2 = -0.284496736
    a3 =  1.421413741
    a4 = -1.453152027
    a5 =  1.061405429
    p  =  0.3275911

    # A&S formula 7.1.26
    t = 1.0/(1.0 + p*x)
    y = 1.0 - (((((a5*t + a4)*t) + a3)*t + a2)*t + a1)*t*math.exp(-x*x)
    return sign*y # erf(-x) = -erf(x)
```

The algorithm comes from [Handbook of Mathematical Functions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486612724), formula 7.1.26.

Comment: You're right. I edited my answer to find the sign of x a different way to fix this problem.  Now it's OK.

Comment: from wikipedia: "the 'handbook' is the work of US federal government [employees], not protected by copyright".  I am putting here a more direct link to the book: http://www.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/frameindex.htm

Comment: I am trying to use this function but passing numpy array to x and return numy array as answer with no success. Can you rewrite array version of the function?

Comment: Is this approximation only for real x?

Answer (score 26):

I would recommend you download [numpy](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=1369&package_id=175103) (to have efficiant matrix in python) and [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) (a  Matlab toolbox substitute, which uses numpy). The erf function lies in scipy.

```
>>>from scipy.special import erf
>>>help(erf)
```

You can also use the erf function defined in pylab, but this is more intended at plotting the results of the things you compute with numpy and scipy. If you want an all-in-one 
installation of these software you can use directly the [Python Enthought distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php).

Comment: SciPy is the motherload of numerical software for Python.  But getting started using it can be a little challenging.  Start by looking at http://www.scipy.org/

Comment: I have to say that I've totally failed to install it. There was a reason that I asked for a package with no external dependencies. Numpy is not the only one. UMFPack is another. It'll be easier to write my own erf()!

Comment: try Python Enthought as I mentioned, they've bundled everything you need.

Comment: 363MB of license-encumbered download is further than I'm willing to go for a 30 line function... as it happens it seems that macports do scipy. It's recompiling the entirety of gcc as I speak. There's something wrong here!

Comment: The example should read "import scipy.special as erf", i.e. get rid of the first "erf" and keep the second. Since erf is a function and not a module, it shouldn't be part of the import path. "import scipy.special as foobar" would work too.  The "as" is a convenience.

Comment: It would be less confusing to "from scipy.special import erf" as that imports only erf function.

Answer (score 8):

A pure python implementation can be found in the mpmath module (http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/)

From the doc string:

```
>>> from mpmath import *
>>> mp.dps = 15
>>> print erf(0)
0.0
>>> print erf(1)
0.842700792949715
>>> print erf(-1)
-0.842700792949715
>>> print erf(inf)
1.0
>>> print erf(-inf)
-1.0
```

For large real `x`, `\mathrm{erf}(x)` approaches 1 very
rapidly::

```
>>> print erf(3)
0.999977909503001
>>> print erf(5)
0.999999999998463
```

The error function is an odd function::

```
>>> nprint(chop(taylor(erf, 0, 5)))
[0.0, 1.12838, 0.0, -0.376126, 0.0, 0.112838]
```

:func:`erf` implements arbitrary-precision evaluation and
supports complex numbers::

```
>>> mp.dps = 50
>>> print erf(0.5)
0.52049987781304653768274665389196452873645157575796
>>> mp.dps = 25
>>> print erf(1+j)
(1.316151281697947644880271 + 0.1904534692378346862841089j)
```

**Related functions**

See also :func:`erfc`, which is more accurate for large `x`,
and :func:`erfi` which gives the antiderivative of
`\exp(t^2)`.

The Fresnel integrals :func:`fresnels` and :func:`fresnelc`
are also related to the error function.

Comment: that's really interesting. presumably this multi-precision implementation is a fair bit slower than using native floating point?

Answer (score 7):

To answer my own question, I have ended up using the following code, adapted from a Java version I found elsewhere on the web:

```
# from: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/21function/ErrorFunction.java.html
# Implements the Gauss error function.
#   erf(z) = 2 / sqrt(pi) * integral(exp(-t*t), t = 0..z)
#
# fractional error in math formula less than 1.2 * 10 ^ -7.
# although subject to catastrophic cancellation when z in very close to 0
# from Chebyshev fitting formula for erf(z) from Numerical Recipes, 6.2
def erf(z):
    t = 1.0 / (1.0 + 0.5 * abs(z))
        # use Horner's method
        ans = 1 - t * math.exp( -z*z -  1.26551223 +
                            t * ( 1.00002368 +
                            t * ( 0.37409196 + 
                            t * ( 0.09678418 + 
                            t * (-0.18628806 + 
                            t * ( 0.27886807 + 
                            t * (-1.13520398 + 
                            t * ( 1.48851587 + 
                            t * (-0.82215223 + 
                            t * ( 0.17087277))))))))))
        if z >= 0.0:
            return ans
        else:
            return -ans
```

Comment: Nice, but as of 2.7 we should do `from math import erf` (for portability, accuracy, speed, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

I have a function which does 10^5 erf calls. On my machine...

scipy.special.erf makes it time at 6.1s

erf Handbook of Mathematical Functions takes     8.3s

erf Numerical Recipes 6.2    takes     9.5s

(three-run averages, code taken from above posters).

Comment: erf called with ctypes from libm.so (standard c math library, 64 bit linux here) goes down to 5.6s.

Comment: I also require 1000s of erf calls. Based on your numbers I'm going with scipy.special.erf. Have you found anything faster since? I've wondered about using a lookup..

Comment: FWIW, how are you using scipy's `erf` function?  With the following setup: `from scipy.special import erf; import numpy as np; data = np.random.randn(10e5)`, I get very fast runtimes from: `result = erf(data)`.  In particular, I get 32ms per loop in that case.  The only way I get runtimes > 1s is if I naively loop over all the elements in a `numpy` array.

Answer (score 6):

One note for those aiming for higher performance: vectorize, if possible.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import erf

def vectorized(n):
    x = np.random.randn(n)
    return erf(x)

def loopstyle(n):
    x = np.random.randn(n)
    return [erf(v) for v in x]

%timeit vectorized(10e5)
%timeit loopstyle(10e5)
```

gives results

```
# vectorized
10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop

# loops
1 loops, best of 3: 2.34 s per loop
```

Comment: 10e5 is really misleading, as it actually means 1000000 (10^6). Also, it has a type of float, but `np.random.randn` accepts only integers (at least in recent versions of NumPy; probably that was not the case 10 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

SciPy has an implementation of the `erf` function, see [scipy.special.erf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.4.1/reference/generated/scipy.special.erf.html).

Answer (score 0):

From [Python's math.erf function documentation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/mathmodule.c), it uses up to 50 terms in the approximation:

```
Implementations of the error function erf(x) and the complementary error
   function erfc(x).
   Method: we use a series approximation for erf for small x, and a continued
   fraction approximation for erfc(x) for larger x;
   combined with the relations erf(-x) = -erf(x) and erfc(x) = 1.0 - erf(x),
   this gives us erf(x) and erfc(x) for all x.
   The series expansion used is:
      erf(x) = x*exp(-x*x)/sqrt(pi) * [
                     2/1 + 4/3 x**2 + 8/15 x**4 + 16/105 x**6 + ...]
   The coefficient of x**(2k-2) here is 4**k*factorial(k)/factorial(2*k).
   This series converges well for smallish x, but slowly for larger x.
   The continued fraction expansion used is:
      erfc(x) = x*exp(-x*x)/sqrt(pi) * [1/(0.5 + x**2 -) 0.5/(2.5 + x**2 - )
                              3.0/(4.5 + x**2 - ) 7.5/(6.5 + x**2 - ) ...]
   after the first term, the general term has the form:
      k*(k-0.5)/(2*k+0.5 + x**2 - ...).
   This expansion converges fast for larger x, but convergence becomes
   infinitely slow as x approaches 0.0.  The (somewhat naive) continued
   fraction evaluation algorithm used below also risks overflow for large x;
   but for large x, erfc(x) == 0.0 to within machine precision.  (For
   example, erfc(30.0) is approximately 2.56e-393).
   Parameters: use series expansion for abs(x) < ERF_SERIES_CUTOFF and
   continued fraction expansion for ERF_SERIES_CUTOFF <= abs(x) <
   ERFC_CONTFRAC_CUTOFF.  ERFC_SERIES_TERMS and ERFC_CONTFRAC_TERMS are the
   numbers of terms to use for the relevant expansions. 

#define ERF_SERIES_CUTOFF 1.5
#define ERF_SERIES_TERMS 25
#define ERFC_CONTFRAC_CUTOFF 30.0
#define ERFC_CONTFRAC_TERMS 50

   Error function, via power series.
   Given a finite float x, return an approximation to erf(x).
   Converges reasonably fast for small x.
```