# Cumulative distribution function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I am searching for a way to calculate the Cumulative distribution function in Javascript. Are there classes which have implemented this? Do you have an idea to get this to work? It does not need to be 100% percent accurate but I need a good idea of the value.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: What does your data look like ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to write my own function with the help of [Is there an easily available implementation of erf() for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457408/is-there-an-easily-available-implementation-of-erf-for-python) and the knowledge from wikipedia.

The calculation is not 100% correct as it is just a approximation.

```
function normalcdf(mean, sigma, to) 
{
    var z = (to-mean)/Math.sqrt(2*sigma*sigma);
    var t = 1/(1+0.3275911*Math.abs(z));
    var a1 =  0.254829592;
    var a2 = -0.284496736;
    var a3 =  1.421413741;
    var a4 = -1.453152027;
    var a5 =  1.061405429;
    var erf = 1-(((((a5*t + a4)*t) + a3)*t + a2)*t + a1)*t*Math.exp(-z*z);
    var sign = 1;
    if(z < 0)
    {
        sign = -1;
    }
    return (1/2)*(1+sign*erf);
}

normalcdf(30, 25, 1.4241); //-> 0.12651187738346226
//wolframalpha.com              0.12651200000000000
```

Comment: function normalcdf(b, a, c) {
        b = (c - b) / Math.sqrt(2 * a * a);
        a = 1 / (1 + 0.3275911 * Math.abs(b));
        a = 1 - ((((1.061405429 * a + -1.453152027) * a + 1.421413741) * a + -0.284496736) * a + 0.254829592) * a * Math.exp(-b * b);
        c = 1;
        0 > b && (c = -1);
        return 0.5 * (1 + c * a)
}; – that should be a bit more compact.

Comment: Are you sure this calculates the CDF? For a normal distribution with M = 30 and SD = 25 Wolframalpha returns 0.126512 at 1.4241: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CDF%28normal+distribution+with+mean%3D+30+and+sd+%3D+25%2C+1.4241%29

Comment: @woobert I verified that the comments in the snippet are wrong, the presented function actually returns an approximation of Wolfram's answer. Editted the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 13):

The [math.js](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs) library provides an [`erf`](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/2b95c65a30a84cdd0d48a3994e194ea339ef9c87/lib/function/special/erf.js) function. Based on a definition found at [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cdf+normal+distribution) , the `cdfNormal`function can be implemented like this in Javascript:

```
const mathjs = require('mathjs')

function cdfNormal (x, mean, standardDeviation) {
  return (1 - mathjs.erf((mean - x ) / (Math.sqrt(2) * standardDeviation))) / 2
}
```

In the [`node.js`](https://nodejs.org/en/) console:

```
> console.log(cdfNormal(5, 30, 25))
> 0.15865525393145707 // Equal to Wolfram Alpha's result at: https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/4935c1cb-c245-4d8d-9668-4d353ad714ec#sidebar=compute
```

Answer (score 6):

This formula will give the correct normal CDF unlike the currently accepted answer

```
function ncdf(x, mean, std) {
  var x = (x - mean) / std
  var t = 1 / (1 + .2315419 * Math.abs(x))
  var d =.3989423 * Math.exp( -x * x / 2)
  var prob = d * t * (.3193815 + t * ( -.3565638 + t * (1.781478 + t * (-1.821256 + t * 1.330274))))
  if( x > 0 ) prob = 1 - prob
  return prob
}
```

This answer comes from  [math.ucla.edu](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/distributions/normal.html?)

Answer (score 4):

This is a brute force implementation, but accurate to more digits of precision.  The approximation above is accurate within 10^-7.  My implementation runs slower (700 nano-sec) but is accurate within 10^-14.  normal(25,30,1.4241) === 0.00022322110257305683, vs wolfram's 0.000223221102572082.

It takes the power series of the standard normal pdf, i.e. the bell-curve, and then integrates the series.

I originally wrote this in C, so I concede some of the optimizations might seem silly in Javascript.

```
function normal(x, mu, sigma) {
    return stdNormal((x-mu)/sigma);
}

function stdNormal(z) {
    var j, k, kMax, m, values, total, subtotal, item, z2, z4, a, b;

    // Power series is not stable at these extreme tail scenarios
    if (z < -6) { return 0; }
    if (z >  6) { return 1; }

    m      = 1;        // m(k) == (2**k)/factorial(k)
    b      = z;        // b(k) == z ** (2*k + 1)
    z2     = z * z;    // cache of z squared
    z4     = z2 * z2;  // cache of z to the 4th
    values = [];

    // Compute the power series in groups of two terms.
    // This reduces floating point errors because the series
    // alternates between positive and negative.
    for (k=0; k<100; k+=2) {
        a = 2*k + 1;
        item = b / (a*m);
        item *= (1 - (a*z2)/((a+1)*(a+2)));
        values.push(item);
        m *= (4*(k+1)*(k+2));
        b *= z4;
    }

    // Add the smallest terms to the total first that
    // way we minimize the floating point errors.
    total = 0;
    for (k=49; k>=0; k--) {
        total += values[k];
    }

    // Multiply total by 1/sqrt(2*PI)
    // Then add 0.5 so that stdNormal(0) === 0.5
    return 0.5 + 0.3989422804014327 * total;
}
```

Comment: That's the solution that gives me identical results to the `NORMSDIST` functions provided by Excel or Google Sheets, all other functions I found give me different results

Comment: This answer is correct whereas the accepted answer is not

Comment: I confirm this matches NORMSDIST in Excel etc and is the only version of it's kind that I could find on the internet after some pretty extensive research! @steve please do DM on Twitter (https://twitter.com/HugoBailey - or another of my socials) as I'd like to buy you a coffee :-)

Answer (score 4):

Due to some needs in the past, i put together an implementation of distribution function in javascript. my library is available at github. You can take a look at https://github.com/chen0040/js-stats

it provides javascript implementation of CDF and inverse CDF for Normal distribution, Student's T distribution, F distribution and Chi-Square Distribution

To use the js lib for obtaining CDF and inverse CDF:

```
jsstats = require('js-stats');

//====================NORMAL DISTRIBUTION====================//

var mu = 0.0; // mean
var sd = 1.0; // standard deviation
var normal_distribution = new jsstats.NormalDistribution(mu, sd);

var X = 10.0; // point estimate value 
var p = normal_distribution.cumulativeProbability(X); // cumulative probability

var p = 0.7; // cumulative probability
var X = normal_distribution.invCumulativeProbability(p); // point estimate value

//====================T DISTRIBUTION====================//

var df = 10; // degrees of freedom for t-distribution
var t_distribution = new jsstats.TDistribution(df);

var t_df = 10.0; // point estimate or test statistic
var p = t_distribution.cumulativeProbability(t_df); // cumulative probability

var p = 0.7;
var t_df = t_distribution.invCumulativeProbability(p); // point estimate or test statistic


//====================F DISTRIBUTION====================//

var df1 = 10; // degrees of freedom for f-distribution
var df2 = 20; // degrees of freedom for f-distribution
var f_distribution = new jsstats.FDistribution(df1, df2);

var F = 10.0; // point estimate or test statistic
var p = f_distribution.cumulativeProbability(F); // cumulative probability


//====================Chi Square DISTRIBUTION====================//

var df = 10; // degrees of freedom for cs-distribution
var cs_distribution = new jsstats.ChiSquareDistribution(df);

var X = 10.0; // point estimate or test statistic
var p = cs_distribution.cumulativeProbability(X); // cumulative probability
```

Comment: Looked at the code at github. Beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look [here](http://statpages.org/scicalc.html), it's a scientific calculator implemented in javascript, it includes `erf` and its author claims no copyright on the implementation.