# std normal cdf, normal cdf, or error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, distribution, probability

Can any of these functions, the standard normal cumulative distribution function, the normal cumulative distribution function, or the error function, be reliably calculated with javascript?

I'd like to have a totally client side solution considering the lack of PECL availability on windows.

Please show me how.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I use these implementations:

```
function cdf(x, mean, variance) {
  return 0.5 * (1 + erf((x - mean) / (Math.sqrt(2 * variance))));
}

function erf(x) {
  // save the sign of x
  var sign = (x >= 0) ? 1 : -1;
  x = Math.abs(x);

  // constants
  var a1 =  0.254829592;
  var a2 = -0.284496736;
  var a3 =  1.421413741;
  var a4 = -1.453152027;
  var a5 =  1.061405429;
  var p  =  0.3275911;

  // A&S formula 7.1.26
  var t = 1.0/(1.0 + p*x);
  var y = 1.0 - (((((a5 * t + a4) * t) + a3) * t + a2) * t + a1) * t * Math.exp(-x * x);
  return sign * y; // erf(-x) = -erf(x);
}
```

Sources:

- cdf: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution
- erf: [Is there an easily available implementation of erf() for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457408/is-there-an-easily-available-implementation-of-erf-for-python)

Error is bound by the erf implementation I think, though this is something which is not really important for me, so you might want to look into that deeper when error is important.

Obviously, to get the standard normal cdf, you pass mean = 0 and variance = 1 to the cdf function, i.e.

```
function std_n_cdf(x) {
  return cdf(x, 0, 1);
}
```