# command for inverse ERF function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

What is the command to calculate Inverse Error function (erf) of a function in a python and which module is needed to import?

Comment: If you want a pure-python solution, there's [pyerf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyerf) which implements the `erf`, `erfc`, and `inverf` functions. It has no dependencies whatsoever. It's also smart enough to use python's `math.erf` and `math.erfc` if they're available.

Comment: Is there any pure python implementation...without scipy or any libraries for erf inverse funcyion?

Comment: Note that pyerf is GPLv3+ only...

Answer (score 18):

For the *inverse* error function, `scipy.special` has `erfinv`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfinv.html#scipy.special.erfinv

```
In [4]: from scipy.special import erfinv

In [5]: erfinv(1)
Out[5]: inf

In [6]: erfinv(0.4)
Out[6]: 0.37080715859355784
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use [scipy](http://www.scipy.org), a library that uses numpy.

the module you need to import to use is erfinv:

```
from scipy.special import erfinv
```

Scipy is a key player for numerical software in Python. But it might be a little challenging getting started with it.